# Backbone/Marionette trying to get attachView to work

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have this Fiddle which illustrates my issue. I'm pretty sure I have it set up correctly, but I keep seeing that Marionette won't render the view.

```
var aApp = new Marionette.Application();

vTestSetup = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "#tmplTest"
});

var testView = new vTestSetup();

aApp.addRegions({
    appRegion: "#dApp"
});

aApp.appRegion.attachView(testView);
aApp.appRegion.show(testView);

aApp.start();
```

[attachView Example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/veector/4AfJk/5/)

Comment: Your JSFiddle is looking for the template in the wrong element. It should be `#sample-template` not `#tmplTest`. Once that's fixed, however, it's not clear what your problem is. If you check your console, you'll get a `Uncaught ReferenceError: contentPlacement is not defined` error. Is `vTestSetup()` a model? If so, please post it's definition. It's also not defined in your JSFiddle

Comment: TL;DR: Your JSFiddle is incomplete. Please complete it

Comment: Sorry, should be complete now.

Comment: Removing the `aApp.appRegion.attachView(testview);` line makes your template render fine. You shouldn't need to `attachView()` if you're doing a `show()`

Comment: You're correct, my question isn't necessarily how to get a view to show, but why does attachView exist if it can't work as above. I have a more complex app where I'd like to attach views that might get shown later. I'm still trying to figure out how attachView should work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18117082/how-to-attach-backbone-marionette-view-to-existing-element-without-creating-extr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you use `attachView` in the case where HTML is already present on the page and you want to add Backbone-managed behavior to it. All you need to do is:

1. Specify an `el` attribute indicating the selector containing the view HTML
2. instantiate a view instance
3. attach the view to the region

You can see a practical example in one of my blog posts (search for attachView): http://davidsulc.com/blog/2012/05/06/tutorial-a-full-backbone-marionette-application-part-1/

Comment: Does the HTML from the view move (or get copied) into the Region's container?

Comment: No, the HTML doesn't get touched (it needs to already be present in the right place). Javascript events realted to the view simply get attached to the existing HTML.